# Is ReactiveCocoa API work the same as RXAndroid ?

Tags: ios, rx-android, reactive-cocoa

Is ReactiveCocoa API work the same as RXAndroid ? 
Can I use it to call multiple requests at the same time and combine the results.

Answer (score 0):

According to a blog post **[Using ReactiveCocoa to parallelize multiple requests](http://mokagio.github.io/tech-journal/2015/06/17/ios-reactive-cocoa-multiple-requests.html)**, by [Giovanni](http://mokagio.github.io/tech-journal/)

This would be possible by using either

> signals combination, and [sic] collection magic.

Read up on the linked article.